# Update statement using WITH clause - Improve time performance

Tags: sql, oracle, common-table-expression

I have this update statement:

```
update crm_acct_inc_mass_bundles
set detinere_pachet='0'
where account in (select account_id 
      from( 
          select account_id, count(distinct product_type_subtype_id) 
          from  dwh_col.co_tran_account_lcl@gdwh24_dwh_col 
          where date_from between '01-oct-2016' and '20-oct-2016'
          group by account_id
          having count(distinct product_type_subtype_id)>1));
```

Is there a way to improve time performance for this statement using `WITH` clause?

Comment: Which dbms are you using? Performance question are almost always product specific.

Comment: @jarlh It's oracle

Comment: Please post the explain plan of the statement; also, it would be useful the DDL of the involved tables, including indexes

Comment: It seems that you are using strings as dates with no conversion; this is really dangerous and, among other problems, can lead Oracle to not use indexes.

Comment: WITH clause will not improve performance (unless you are talking about your own performance in writing and maintaining the code - it can make YOU more productive). WITH clause helps make the code cleaner, more readable and more self-documenting, but if your subquery is not used more than once in the outer query, the optimizer will treat it EXACTLY as a subquery. If the query is used repeatedly, then a WITH clause *may* help improve performance (but not always).

Comment: You might try changing the `IN` located in your where to an `EXISTS`. It could change nothing or it might help the optimizer put together a better plan.